# How does a Clinch affect DVs in Scion 1E?

Tags: weapons, grapple, scion

Hero (pg 202) gives the stats for lots of weapons, including the three flavors of unarmed attack, which further includes the Clinch/grapple, the subject of this question. However, instead of listing a modifier to use to your DVs while using this action, it just has a flat line.

Does that mean your DVs are set to zero? Is it an editing error? Or just a poorly phrased way of saying +0? I can't find clarifying rules text in either the description of the 'weapon' or in the attack rules for grappling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured this one out.

The Defense stat of a weapon determines your Parry DV (Hero pg. 201).

> Add Defense to the character’s (Dexterity + Melee) before dividing by two to calculate Parry DV with that weapon.

But you can have multiple Parry DVs; one for each weapon you have equipped, plus unarmed (Hero pg. 192).

> A character can have many Parry DVs (Parry DVs). You use Parry DV when your character knocks an attack aside with a weapon or blocks one with his arms or legs. Characters automatically have an unarmed Parry DV, and most have additional Parry DVs based on their weapons.

So when the table (Hero pg. 202) says that Clinch has a Defense of "-", what it's actually saying is that you don't get a separate Parry DV for your Clinch. You don't grapple your opponent's weapon to block it unarmed; you knock it aside with your fist or foot or head, using the Light Unarmed Defense value or the Heavy Unarmed Defense value (which is worse, so this would be purely a flex, perhaps representing stopping their attack dead by, e.g., catching their fist).